# Using 'undefined' as a key in an object causes `undefined` to be used as the key. Why?

Tags: javascript

As in, `{'undefined': 'foo'}` results in `{undefined: 'foo'}`.

In Chrome:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

In Firefox:

[image: Firefox Screenshot]

In Safari:

[image: Safari Screenshot]

Why? I tried other reserved words (e.g., `null` and `true`) and those seem to get converted as well.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the output of the console mechanism. It's working exactly like you think it should work. The console mechanism doesn't include quotes around property names when they're not necessary.

Comment: Also, unlike `true` and `null`, `undefined` is **not** a reserved word.

Comment: Pointy's right. You can verify this really easily by trying the same thing with eg  var o = {'foo': 'bar'} !

Comment: I never use quotes when defining keys on object literals. Is that necessary?

Comment: All keys are strings.

Comment: @KimGysen when the object property isn't a valid identifier (like "@property-name"), you have to use quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with reserved words. Object keys are displayed this way no matter what string you use for the key. It's just how it's being interpreted/presented for you at the console.

```
var o = {'cheese': 'foo'};
// Object {cheese: "foo"}

o.cheese; // "foo"
o['cheese']; // "foo"
```

The quotes are unnecessary for accessing, so they are removed.